# sqlalchemy: applying an SQL-like date() function on a datetime column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I would like to group by date and count the resulting number of `id`'s using sqlalchemy.

Unfortunately, my column containing date information `created_datetime` is a datetime and I would like to use an sql function like

`group by date(created_datetime)`

in order to group by date.

Here is what I have so far...

```
conn = engine.connect()

s = my_db.my_table.alias()

q = select([s.c.id]).\
    group_by(s.c.created_datetime).\
    count()

result = conn.execute(q)

for i in result:
    print(i)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func) for this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

q = select([s.c.id]).\
    group_by(func.date(s.c.created_datetime)).\
    count()
```